# Cannot find module @components - Angular custom modules/barrels

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I am trying to restructure my project but i have a small problem. I have one project which works correctly but in project which i am working rightnow custom modules does not work.

I have created directory components and put there "barrel" for components as index.ts. In the tsconfig i have created paths to it. In the App.Module i imported this barrel and put it in declarations. After running project i am getting error
'Cannot find module '@components'

I would be not dissapointed with that but if i display tooltip on the import i see correct path.

[image]

In my opinion i have created wrong configuration. I am leaving some simple codes with configuration and simple architecture on StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqcn5g?file=angular.json

Best regards.

Comment: have you included @components in your tsconfig file??

Comment: Yup. In the stackblitz i created the same tsconfig as i have in my project. There is included